# Show my shop in google maps without search

Tags: dictionary

I have a problem with google maps, I register my business on google and want to add location, after adding by following google's instruction (add missing place) I can see the building just after searching by name. Desire result is to see the building without search by concrete name.

Comment: This is not related to programming.

Comment: I don't think this site is the right place to ask such questions, this website is for coding/algorithms related questions.